How to remove extra blank page at the end of compiled PDF when using includepdf?
I'm encountering a problem related to \includepdf where my compiled PDF (which is more than 1 page) always has an extra blank page at the very end, even though my PDF file doesn't contain any blank pages. How can I remove this? I already tried other answers I found such as includepdf outputs blank pages but didn't work.
\documentclass[aps,prl,superscriptaddress,longbibliography,showpacs,twocolumn]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\let\LS@rot\@undefined}
\makeatother

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{quantikz}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

text blah blah..

\bibliography{ref}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-2}

\clearpage %\mbox{} 
\setcounter{page}{1}\includepdf[pages={1,{},2}] {test1.pdf}

\end{document}

Update: After experimenting with various options, I finally figured it out. You can use the following prompt:
\foreach \x in {1,...,N}
{%
\clearpage
\includepdf[pages={\x}]{test1.pdf}
}


The revtex class redefines \newpage (and other stuff) and that means that \includepdf can no longer place the pages properly on their own page. It works if you insert the pages one by one:
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\let\LS@rot\@undefined}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

text blah blah..

\clearpage 
\setcounter{page}{1}
\includepdf[pages={1}] {example-image-letter-numbered.pdf}
\clearpage
\includepdf[pages={2}] {example-image-letter-numbered.pdf}
\end{document}



Thank you. I ended up finding a proper way to address the issue, which I briefly mentioned in the post (it's essentially the same as yours).

I replaced test1.pdf which is not generally avalable by example-image-letter-numbered.pdf which is a test file available for tests.
You are forcing a blank page with the \mbox{} after \clearpage.
Removing the \mbox{} produces

\documentclass[aps,prl,superscriptaddress,longbibliography,showpacs,twocolumn]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\let\LS@rot\@undefined}
\makeatother

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{quantikz}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

text blah blah..

\bibliography{PRL_ref}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-2}

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}\includepdf[pages={1}] {example-image-letter-numbered.pdf}

\end{document}


Thank you for the comment. But I encountered another problem: if I include page 2, then the first two pages overlap. This can be solved by using pages={1,{},2}, but then the the extra blank page in the end pops out. I edited my original question accordingly.

@LeeseokKim But you still haven't removed the \mbox{} from your example.

You're right, I just did. But the problem is still there.
